# В приходящем письме не отображается телефон, просто пустота. Все остальное есть

Tags: php

Вот сама форма

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" class="single-form" action="php/mail.php">

<div class="message col-xs-12">
<div class="inner"> 
<p class="email-loading"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sending...</p>
<p class="email-success"><i class="icon icon-icon-check-alt2"></i> Your quote has successfully been sent.</p>
<p class="email-failed"><i class="icon icon-icon-close-alt2"></i> Something went wrong!</p>

</div> <!-- End: .inner -->
</div> <!-- End: .message -->


<div class="col-sm-4">
<input name="name" class="contact-name form-control" id="contact-name" type="text" placeholder="Name"  required="">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
<input name="email" class="contact-email form-control" id="contact-email" type="email" placeholder="Email"  required="">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
<input name="Phone" class="contact-name2 form-control" id="Phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"  required="">
</div>                                                                
<div class="col-sm-12">
<input name="subject" class="contact-subject form-control" id="contact-subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject"  required="">
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
<textarea name="message" class="contact-message form-control" id="contact-message" rows="3" placeholder="Message" required=""></textarea>
</div>

<!-- Subject Button -->
<div class="btn-form text-center col-xs-12">
<button class="btn btn-fill right-icon">отправить сообщение<i class="icon icons8-advance"></i></button>
</div>
</form>
```

А вот обработчик

```
<?php
// Variables
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$Phone = trim($_POST['Phone']);
$subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);


if( isset($name) ) {

    // Avoid Email Injection and Mail Form Script Hijacking
    $pattern = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
    if( preg_match($pattern, $name) || preg_match($pattern, $message)  ) {
        exit;
    }

    // Email will be send
    $to = "molchanov.artem.1994@gmail.com";
    //$to = "hrolenko.a@gmail.com"; // innaeger@gmail.com Change with your email address
    $sub = "$subject from Cv"; // You can define email subject
    // HTML Elements for Email Body



$body = ' 
        Имя отправителя:'.$name.' 
        Контактный телефон:'.$Phone.' 
        Контактный email:'.$email.' 
        Сообщение:'.$message; 
//Must end on first column

    $headers = "Заявка на инсталляцию: $name\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // PHP email sender
    mail($to, $sub, $body, $headers);
}


?>
```

JS

```
$("#contact-form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var success = $(this).find('.email-success'),
    failed = $(this).find('.email-failed'),
    loader = $(this).find('.email-loading'),
    postUrl = $(this).attr('action');

var data = {
    name: $(this).find('.contact-name').val(),
    email: $(this).find('.contact-email').val(),
    phone: $(this).find('.contact-phone').val(),
    subject: $(this).find('.contact-subject').val(),
    message: $(this).find('.contact-message').val()
};

if ( isValidEmail(data['email']) && (data['message'].length > 1) && (data['name'].length > 1) ) {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: postUrl,
              data: data,
              beforeSend: function() {
                loader.fadeIn(1000);
              },
              success: function(data) {
                loader.fadeOut(1000);
                success.delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
                failed.fadeOut(500);
              },
              error: function(xhr) { // if error occured
                loader.fadeOut(1000);
                failed.delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
                success.fadeOut(500);
              },
              complete: function() {
                loader.fadeOut(1000);
              }
            });
          } else {
            loader.fadeOut(1000);
            failed.delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
            success.fadeOut(500);
          }

          return false;
        });
```

Comment: Можно попробовать в обработчике проверить Phone 
print_r($_POST['Phone'])); exit();
Доходит значение Phone до обработчика ?

Comment: @Arsen не доходит, не пойму почему

Comment: Понятно, может попробовать поменять name='phone", теоретически разницы не должно быть, если не трудно поменяй
<input name="phone" class="contact-name2 form-control" id="Phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"  required="">

Comment: проверил Ваш пример с тегом формы <form action="/indexes.php" method="POST">, всё сработало, Вы не могли бы отобразить свой тег form

Comment: @LeshaZ   <form id="contact-form" method="post" class="single-form" action="php/sendmail.php">

Comment: @Arsen уже менял )

Comment: Артём, а как Вы отсылаете данные ajax или простым сабмитом с перегрузкой?

Comment: @LeshaZ используется ajax

Comment: тогда проверьте как забираются данные в js, а лучше сюда выкатите

Comment: @LeshaZ выкатил

Comment: судя по коду ищет инпут с классом contact-phone НО в вёрстке имеем
name="Phone" class="contact-name2....
мне кажется тут собака зарыта

Comment: @LeshaZ да, я тоже так подумал и изменил, но все равно работать не начало <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input name="phone" class="contact-phone form-control" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"  required="">
                                </div>

Comment: значит после var data пишем console.log(data) и смотрим есть данные или нет

Comment: кстати ключ в объекте data phone а на сервере  Phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по ответам в комментах, Вам следует

1) Исправить в `<input name="Phone" class="contact-name2 form-control" id="Phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"  required="">` класс contact-name2 на contact-phone

2) На стороне сервера исправить ключ Phone на phone или на стороне js в объекте data исправить phone на Phone

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
   name: $(this).find('.contact-name').val(),
   email: $(this).find('.contact-email').val(),
   phone: $(this).find('.contact-phone').val(), // В этой строчке ошибка. Нужно phone: $(this).find('.contact-name2').val()
   subject: $(this).find('.contact-subject').val(),
   message: $(this).find('.contact-message').val()
};
```

В форме нет .contact-phone. Поэтому на сервер отправляется пустое значение

В пхп файле нужно заменить

```
$Phone = trim($_POST['Phone']); на 
$Phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
```